# File program - fseek isnt working

Tags: c, file, fseek

I'm having trouble making this fseek() function work in my code. The text I wrote just doesn't start at the point I indicate and I don't know why. It should start writing from the \n and it just overwrite all the text file. Even if I open it with `a` it just doesn't go where I command through the parameters.

```
   fclose(file);
    FILE *file_a = fopen("ex6.txt", "w");

    fseek(file_a, -1, SEEK_END);

    puts("Write text to add:");
    while((letter = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        fputc(letter, file_a);
    };
```

What is happening? Why doesnt this work?

Comment: If you want the end of the file, I expect you want to pass `0` to fseek. `-1` would be 1 byte before the end.

Comment: Are you trying to insert into the file near the end rather than just append to the end?

Comment: Sorry that information is missed. I'm trying to add text, lets say 2 characters before the end, so imagine this is my file content: "hello\0"
I would like to insert information "hell | o\0", overwriting "o\0" and put there my own test like " yeah" and the final product would be: "hell yeah".

But it's just like fseek doesn't correspond to what i'm asking, even if I put the reference in positive numbers...

Comment: What is your platform? Maybe this could be related? -> "Library implementations are allowed to not meaningfully support SEEK_END (therefore, code using it has no real standard portability)."  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/

Comment: In fact I opened in "w+" mode and now it's all good. Seems like it doesn't support the simple "w" or "a". Thanks for the answers, guys. It was very helpful.

Comment: Write mode truncates any existing file to zero length.

Comment: To expand: `w` truncates the file (if it exists), fseek() would allow you to hop around once you've started putting stuff in it. `a` and `a+` **always** write to the end of the file. As you've found, `w+` keeps any existing content, allowing you to extend/overwrite.

Answer (score 3):

Navigating to absolute only works when the file is opened in binary mode. When it's opened in text mode, `fseek()` cannot navigate to absolute positions in a file besides 0 (the start of the file), and trying to do so will result in undefined behaviour. You can, however, navigate to references in the file returned by `ftell()`. The reason for this is due to the handling of certain characters by some operating systems; some implementations allow it but POSIX doesn't mandate it.

I know you solved the issue in the comments, this is just for closure.